# jQuery, how to rebind html-elements after .load()

Tags: jquery

I have a html-component that will be reload after a button has been clicked. 
Some elements of the component are bound to click and hover handlers.
Everything is working fine until the `.load()`-function is called to reload the component.
The elements of the loaded component are not bound to corresponding handlers.

At that point I put the js-script at the end of the component, so that it binds the elements.
But after the components relaod the elemnts outside the component are unbound, now.

I've tried it with `.on()`, `.live()`, `.bind()`, `.click()`, ... nothing worked.

Comment: `$( document ).on( '#selector' )`. If that doesn't work, you need to show the code you have.

Comment: show attempts you've made along with sample html.. clearly not using delegation methods properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call the `.load()` method AND create a callback in which you can rebind the elements.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...initially bind all event handlers for page (including elements to be reloaded)...

    $("#someButton").on("click", function() { 
        $("#elementToReload").load("page-to-load.html", function() {
             ...bind all event handlers for this and containing elements here...
        });
    });
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions on this. Good luck! :)

Comment: can certainly do it this way, but for simple event handlers OP concept of delegation will defintiely work if executed with proper syntax

Comment: @charlietfl - yes, that is very true - that's why I included the bit about using `.on` in my original solution. I think that you are right that the use of the delegation methods should be emphasized, based on the OP, so I have added an example for `.on`, as well.

Comment: actually your load method won't work, most elements don't trigger a load event. The AJAX load method has a complete callback where you would do the binding. Also, your `on` syntax won't work , the selector needs to be a permanent asset, then use `target selector` argument. `$(selector).load(url,function(){ /* bind code here*/})`

Comment: that's it, putting the function call into the load('path', function() part solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem - It's what we are here for :)

Comment: How to bind??
`...bind all event handlers for this and containing elements here...` this line should be upgraded to provide a bind function to make an answer high value :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the way you are binding your events, but basically, if you are doing something in this way :

```
$('.your-class').on('click', function (e) {[...]});
```

You may have better to delegate it to the document, that is not reloaded.

```
$(document).on('click', '.your-class', function (e) {[...]});
```

You can be sure that even the elements that does not exists at the script execution time will be binded aswell, be cause they will be a part of your document, later.