# Load page via ajax (without php)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to create a ajax page load without php?
So just load the content of the linked page (if intern) and insert it into the current page.

I tried this, but it does not work (just nothing happens, when I click a link):
http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/jquery-tutorial-ajax-load-content-with-no-page-refresh/

My code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set trigger and container variables
    var trigger = $('a'),
        container = $('#content');

    // Fire on click
    trigger.on('click', function(){
      // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
      var $this = $(this),
        target = $this.data('target');       

      // Load target page into container
      container.load(target);

      // Stop normal link behavior
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `target`?

Comment: Most links on my page do not have any target. So I guess it would be `target="_self"`

Comment: `load` function takes real link as argument, link to real page.  if your target is `_self` or even empty - nothing will be loaded.

Comment: The links are real (or what are unreal links?). So I can`t use it for internal links? page.com/about to page.com/blog

Comment: Do you understand what I said? What is the value of `target = $this.data('target');`?

Comment: I guess I did not understand. I`m no jquery pro and only took the script from the linked page above. Can you please give me a link or shortly explain what it means?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery method `load` takes a link to page as an argument. It can be `/blog/post` or `blog/about.html` or whatever.

What does this code do:

```
trigger.on('click', function(){
    // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
    var $this = $(this),

    // takes value of data-target attribute 
    target = $this.data('target');        

    // and pass it to load function
    container.load(target);
```

This means that if your `a` element has no `data-target` attribute - then there's **no link** available. And empty string passed to `container.load(target);`
How do you think what will be loaded if empty string passed to a function? **Nothing**.

So you should add data-target attribute to your links:

```
<a href="#" data-target="/blog/post.html">Click</a>
```

**Update**:

As it turns out `load` method allows to load parts of page like this:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

More data on [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: And when I do a `$('a').each(function() { $link = $(this).attr('href'); $(this).attr('data-target', $link); });`? Can I only load some parts of the linked page? E.g. only the content placed in `#content`

Comment: Generally not, but you can try to use loaded content as another jquery object, find something there, clone and etc

Comment: Update my answer. Read it.

Comment: Ok great thank you! One last thing: I implemented it here: http://demo.comboot.io/3.1/ Every second click does not work. **Edit: This fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16001691/2977288**